# Attribute all values not showing on product catalog in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created a attribute with 30 values,but inside the create product page only 7 values is showing,why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure under Advanced Attribute Properties the Scope is set to Global.

Then reindex

```
bin/magento index:reindex
```